# How to add a simple Marker in Mapbox GL?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js

Since the Mapbox GL documentation doesn't talk about anything regarding adding simple markers to LngLat coordinates, and really only has documentation on how to add custom markers, I was hoping someone could tell me how you're supposed to get Mapbox-gl.js to actually add a marker to passed LngLat coords.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a marker to a MapBox GL JS map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44208200/how-to-add-a-marker-to-a-mapbox-gl-js-map)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good news! In the newest release of mapbox-gl-js (v0.21.0) a new `Marker` class was added that provides the functionality you're looking for:

https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#marker

https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/custom-marker-icons/