# Mapbox GL JS cannot see marker

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl, mapbox-marker

I'm trying to add a normal Marker, no special icon or image, just the default pin like icon to the map. I can see that the marker container is created but I cannot see it on the screen.

```
<script>
  mapboxgl.accessToken = 'x';
  var monument = [-77.0353, 38.8895];
  var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v9',
    center: monument,
    zoom: 15
  });
  map.on('load', function() {
    var marker = new mapboxgl.Marker()
    .setLngLat([-77.0353, 38.8895])
    .addTo(map);

  });

</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a marker to a MapBox GL JS map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44208200/how-to-add-a-marker-to-a-mapbox-gl-js-map)

Comment: There's no such thing as "default pin". See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44208200/how-to-add-a-marker-to-a-mapbox-gl-js-map